# How to straighten image along the path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, panorama

I've merged some pictures into panorama and it looks like a rainbow. See my below picture:

[image: Failed Panorama]

I wonder if there is a photoshop tool which allows me to draw/indicate a curved path and then have the tool automatically adjust the image until the path is a straight horizontal line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start by trying [Puppet Warp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS36B5BBD7-ACCE-4608-AF31-9DACE770576A.html#WS2b33cd566cc765715d0271451243bc8da1d-7ffe).

Just go to `Edit -> Puppet Warp` and pin your image in in the center, and then add pins to either side.

Then simply click-and-drag the points on the side to straighten the image.

Comment: You're very welcome; and if my answer satisfied your question don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

`Edit > Transform > Warp...`

Comment: Look like it transforms the path, not the image, doesn't it?

Comment: It transforms the path if the path is highlighted. Highlight the layer with the image on it. Although, you've got a curved path and are asking how to "straighten" something on a curved path. That makes little sense to me.

Comment: Currently, the image is curved. I want it straight from the left through the right, same as what's done on some panorama made by smartphone.

Comment: I think what @tu tran is asking is: is there a photoshop tool which allows him/her to draw/indicate a curved path and then have the tool automatically adjust the image until the path is a straight horizontal line.

Comment: if one were to record an action while applying warp to the path, committing the warp action (hitting the check mark), then stopping the recording, the action can be replayed on the image layer.

Comment: @horatio: Your first comment is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

The much easier way to do this is to use 'Filter → Adaptive Wide Angle', then set the option in the right dropdown to Panorama. Use the tool that is already selected when the window pops up and click on each end of a section that should be straight. The after the line is placed, right click it and select Horizontal or Vertical. This will adjust the entire image around those points and is much more accurate and much easier to use than puppet warp.